# Compilation error with LuaLaTeX

Tags: errors, luatex

I try to compile this code without success.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode,luatextra,luaotfload}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
tex.print("\\begin{tabular}{c|c}")
tex.print("x & y \\\\\\hline")
for i=-1,5,1.0 do
  tex.print(..i "&" ..-i^2 + 5*i - 8 "\\\\\\hline")
end
tex.print("\\end{tabular}")
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

The compilation returns the following message :

```
! LuaTeX error [string "\directlua "]:4: unexpected symbol near '..'.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }

l.13 \end{luacode*}


?
```

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, you might consider accepting it. This way future users see immediately that they can "trust" the accepted answer.

Comment: And the error is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have it almost correct:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode,luatextra,luaotfload}

\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
tex.print("\\begin{tabular}{c|c}")
tex.print("x & y \\\\\\hline")
for i=-1,5 do
  tex.print(i .. "&" ..-i^2 + 5*i - 8 .. "\\\\\\hline")
end
tex.print("\\end{tabular}")
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

You have the `..` in the wrong place. (And a missing `document` environment, but that is obvious :-))

[image: screenshot_with_table]

Comment: @topskipI actually forgot `\begin{document}`, it is a blunder !
For bad positioning `..`, this is my first code with Lua.
How to replace `tex.print("x & y \\\\\\hline")` by `tex.print("$x$ & $f(x)$ \\\\\\hline")` ?

Comment: @Fabrice Replacing the line works just fine. I don't see a problem in the code.